# Is it possible to create custom Viber stickers?

Tags: android, viber

I have been thinking about developing my own custom Viber sticker but I can't get to any good source to give me some information about this.

Does anyone know how to do this? Or is it possible at all? If yes, please let me know what do I need to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same question, is there any one to answer this question?

Comment: just simple.. keep a collection in your phone.. and send as pictures.. it wil behave same.. even if you want to share with friends.. when you 'll send them they will have this collection too :P

Answer (score 6):

When you send/recieve a sticker, it doesnt really send it, just opens the image from the local store from your phone.
What I did on my Android is download a stickers set that I dont like.
Connect the phone to the computer and open the vyber folder, and search for the folder containing the set I downloaded. 
Then I uploaded my custom stickers to this folder using the same names to overwrite the files.

Since vyber doesnt send the stickers, when you send the custom sticker people dont see your stikers, they see the original files on their phones. So I repeat the process on the phones of my boyfriend and my sister.

I can only use the stickers with them, but it is better than nothing.
Also you can just have a folder in your gallery and send them as image files is not the same, but it works.